# Using BigQuery Storage API through Spark: Requested multiple partitions but getting only 1

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm using bigquery-spark-connector to read from BigQuer, which uses BigQuery Storage API. My script (automatically) requests multiple partitions from BigQuery Storage API but I get the warning:

WARN com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.direct.DirectBigQueryRelation: Requested 2 partitions, but only received 1 from the BigQuery Storage API

The Spark job takes very long and I think it's because it's not reading through multiple partitions. How can I make sure that BigQuery Storage API gives me all the partitions I'm asking for? What's happening here, why is it only giving me a single partition, no matter how many I request?

First I create a SparkSession:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
.appName("XXX")
.getOrCreate();
```

This is the code causing the WARN:

```
Dataset<Row> data = spark.read()
.format("bigquery")
.option("table","project.dataset.table")
.load()
.cache();
```

Comment: How large is your table?

Comment: I tried with multiple tables. The table where it tries to make 2 partitions is 977.25MB, If I try with a larger table it tries for even more partitions, but I always just receive 1 partition from Storage API, no matter the size of the table I'm reading from.

Answer (score 1):

The spark-bigquery-connector uses some heuristics to ask when asking for partitions from the BigQuery storage API. The returned partitions are the actual partitions that BigQuery uses, which may be lower than what the heuristics has predicted. This is a normal case, so perhaps a warning is a bit too severe for this case (I've discussed this also with the BigQuery team). For further context read the description of the requestedStreams parameter [here](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-clients/latest/com/google/cloud/bigquery/storage/v1beta1/BigQueryStorageClient.html#createReadSession-com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1beta1.TableReferenceProto.TableReference-java.lang.String-int-).

The second issue is that the Spark job takes very long. If increasing the resources - especially the number of executors doesn't help, please open a bug in the [spark-bigquery-connector project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-bigquery-connector) with the actual stream id and the rest of the spark configuration so that the connector and BoigQuery teams would be able to check it out.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I'm not sure this is causing the job to run slowly, it's the first thing I'm investigating because of the WARN. Do you think this could be causing the job to run slowly or should I look elsewhere?

Comment: What is the size of the cluster? how many executors do you have? Where does your Spark job run - locally, Dataproc, EMR, other? Is it near the data - same region or another region? Is the actual reading slow or the following data processing?

Comment: I'm running it on Dataproc, just the default cluster 1 master, 2 workers, 4 CPUs each, only testing at the moment. And you're right, the reading is actually fast, I tested all steps separately, and it turns out it's the .write that's slowing it. I'm using it with .mode("append").partitionBy("column").csv("gs://output/path"). Any tips on speeding that up?

Comment: If you have just one partition all the writing will be done serially. Try to re-partition the data to the default partitioning, so the write will be distributed.

Comment: I know what you mean, it will be faster to write like that. I use the partitionBy("id_column") to get individual output files for each id containing all its values. I don't know how I would do that without the partitionBy().

Comment: You can try either df.repartition(<number of unique ids>, col("id")). Notice that your ids should the range of [0,n). If this is not the case, You need to create a mapping of id -> [0,n) first, add this value to the each row and repartition based on the [0,n) value.